# Starting Apache when running in port 8080 as a normal user

Tags: apache-2.2

From the Apache [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/invoking.html) can be read:

> If the [Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) specified in the configuration file is default of 80 (or any other port below 1024), then it is necessary to have root privileges in order to start apache, so that it can bind to this privileged port.

After reading this, I immediately made the assumption that if I was running apache on port 8080, I wouldn't need to use `sudo` to restart the service. But as it turns out, I still need to use `sudo`, no matter what port I use.

Did I misunderstood the documentation? Or did something get misconfigured in my installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is generally configured to start as root and then to setuid to the apache user by default.

If root started the apache server, then you will need to be root to restart it regardless of the port you are using.

If you start it as user X, you need to be user X to restart it. It's also likely to require some special configuration as the setuid call will fail if it is not started as root.

Comment: That means that if I `sudo service apache2 stop`, then I should be able to immediately `service apache2 start`, right? But I still get a permission error.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `(13)Permission denied: AH00091: apache2: could not open error log file /var/log/apache2/error.log.`

Comment: Your user does not have permission to write to the log files. You should be using a different set of config files that use your home directory to store data.

Comment: But the config files are as well writable only by the root. I understand what you are trying to say, but it feels like apache is very un-friendly to non-root users. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: You would create your own copies of the config files. This is designed for security purposes, why are you not running apache as root anyways?

Comment: I am running it as root. I was just reading the documentation and I found this feature, so I tried it out of curiosity.